# Does this constitute a function space?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let the collection of the family of functions be defined as $K = \{\Phi_1, \Phi_2, \Phi_3,\cdots\}$ where
$$\Phi_1(x)=\Phi(s_1,x)=\zeta(s_1)^{1/\text{log}(x)},\\
\Phi_2(x)=\Phi(s_2,x)=\zeta(s_2)^{1/\text{log}(x)},
$$
and so on. Here $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann Zeta function, $x\in(0,1)$, $ \Phi\in(0,1)$ and $s>1$.

Each function $\Phi_k$ is bounded in the unit square for $x\in(0,1)$, so my question is: Does this constitute a function space? The space is closed under multiplication and not addition so it is not a linear space. What is an example of a nonlinear function space?

Here is a picture of what a sample of these functions look like in the unit square:

[image]

Comment: The term "function space" does not have any precise standard definition.  Is there some definition you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eric Wofsey clearly stated in [his comment to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814945/does-this-constitute-a-function-space/2820002#comment5805137_2814945), the term "function space" has not any precise standard definition. However, according to the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space), a *Function space* is a set of functions having the same domain and codomain: Gel'fand and Fomin ((1963) Ch. 1, §2 p. 4) remark that the origin of this locution comes from the usefulness of using this "geometric" language when studying functionals, i.e. thinking of functions belonging to a set as points belonging to an abstract space. Following this point of view, we can define a set of functions $\mathfrak{F}$ a function space if

1. all the its member functions $f\in\mathfrak{F}$ have the same domain and codomain, say $X$ and $Y$.
2. the share other properties (and this make them interesting to study as a single mathematical object).

And according to such a definition, $K$ *is a function space*: precisely, since it is closed respect to multiplication, it is a function space having a *[monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid)* structure. However,  Gel'fand and Fomin ((1963) Ch. 1, §2 p. 4) clearly base their analogy on the geometry of *finite dimensional vector spaces* and, as shown by pcp in his answer and also remarked in the OP, $K$ *is not a linear vector space*. In such cases, i.e. when functions having the same domain and codomain share also other interesting properties, it is perhaps more correct to use the word *class* to identify them as a single mathematical object: example of such use of the nomenclature are the *[Laguerre–Pólya class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre%E2%80%93P%C3%B3lya_class)* which, like $K$, is not a vector space but is a monoid, or the *Pólya-Haussdorff class*. In sum **it is not wrong to say that $K$ is a function space, but is customary to say that it is a class of functions**.

[1] Gelfand, I. M.; Fomin, S. V. (1965)[1963], Silverman, R. A., ed., *Calculus of variations*, Englewood Cliffs, N.J.: Prentice-Hall Inc., pp. VII+232, MR 0160139, Zbl 0127.05402.

Answer (score 0):

For $x\to 0$ you see that all functions approach either the value 1 or 0. This property is not invariant under linear operations such as taking sums and rescaling functions. Hence your system is not a linear space.

I am assuming, of course, that a 'function space' should first of all be a linear space.

Comment: For x approaching 0 all the functions approach only  1

Comment: What if s is a root of the Zeta function?

Comment: Good call @pcp !

Comment: I'm not sure but that's an interesting question

Comment: it would just give you another curve in the unit square

Comment: Actually it would just equal zero because zero to any power still equals 0

Comment: Absolutely correct, but anyhow, the associated system does not form a linear space.

Comment: Okay but it's closed under multiplication because if you multiply any curve by another curve in the space you get another curve in the space